# When is the final explanation in Lost revealed?

Tags: lost

I am watching Lost and have just finished watching s02e18 (Dave). I realized, what if all this is some figment of imagination or in some way not real? I would be aghast if this were the case.

That got me worried. I am sure it won't be that stupid. I am dying to know more but each episode takes 40 min and does not reveal much. One thing I am dying to know is, will the ultimate explanation, i.e. what exactly is happening on the island be completely revealed in the last episode of last season only or it will be revealed before the final season and then the story will proceed? (You can tell me which season I can expect it to be).

Please do not put any kind of spoiler.

If you think that knowing the answer to this question is a spoiler in itself or will spoil the rest of the show for me, please just say so and do not answer.

Comment: there's one important thing you need to know before going on watching: the creators said all the time that they had the ending planned from the beginning. They lied.

Comment: @Luciano I am already pretty convinced of it.

Comment: Just watch the whole thing.  There's no point in giving away the whole show before the last season, so you're going to have to continue watching.

Comment: @Luciano I strongly disagree with you, but this isn't the best place to discuss that since we wouldn't want to spoil anything.  I'll just say this: if you haven't rewatched it I suggest you do, because it's remarkable to see all the hints buried in the show.

Answer (score 6):

The first three seasons mainly just set up the mysteries of the show, they don't provide many answers, apart from a few answers at the end of Season 3.  Concerning seasons 4 and season 5, the creators of Lost said season 4 would ask two more questions for every one question it answered, whereas season 5 would answer two questions for every one additional question it asked.  And then season 6 is where you get the complete answers to the biggest mysteries of Lost.  (Some people say Lost didn't answer enough questions, but I disagree with them for the most part.  There's one relatively minor mystery they intentionally didn't address, but mostly they did a good job in resolving the mysteries of the show.)

In any case, to answer your question, no, this is not the kind of show where the show just keeps going on long after all mysteries have been resolved.  Mystery is an element throughout the show.

There's one more thing I can say: the creators of Lost said that they had a rule that every time you encountered the Monster, we would learn something new about it.

Comment: Some of the questions it answered, such as "What's the story behind Jack's tattoos", I'm not sure anyone was asking in the first place.

Answer (score 4):

> I realized, what if all this is some figment of imagination or in some way not real? I would be aghast if this were the case.

Be prepared to be aghast.  At least on some level.  However, the entire series is worth watching, even if the 4th season is a bit slow.  What is actually happening on the island is not revealed in the final episode; by then you already know what's going on but there are still some questions left unanswered.

Comment: I just finished season 2, they didn't answer a single question and raised a lot too many more. Now season 3 is another 23 episodes... May be I will take a break for a week or something. It is irritating..

Comment: @BhaskarVashishth Well, in the season 2 finale you got a small answer, which is that Desmond crashed Oceanic 815 and that pushing the button in the hatch is about discharging the buildup of excess charge every 108 minutes.  In any case, I suggest you keep watching.  The first half of season 3 isn't that good, but after that it becomes really good.

Comment: This is another can of worms, but I disagree that there are unanswered questions. I recently rewatched the entire show over the course of a month and every mystery has an explanation.

Comment: @sanpaco Yes, I agree with you that almost everything is answered.  There is one minor mystery which the creators intentionally chose not to resolve, but apart from that the show did a good job of answering questions.

Comment: 99% of the conversations I've had where people thought something was unanswered, it turned out they either missed the explanation or simply didn't like it and refused to accept it.

Answer (score 0):

*LOST's* mythological semantics are never entirely spelled out to it's audience, but hinted at with characters like Daniel Faraday. IMO you can piecemeal some of it together once you understand what a particular time line is, during the final season, which is somewhat explained in the final episode through dialogue and/or choices characters make, helping to establish the series' metaphysics, but though spiritual reverence.

*LOST* relied on what both the characters and audience didn't know, but with evidence given to **begin to understand** what the Island really is, what the Island is for, and a revelation that we, the audience, really only glimpsed one iteration of something much much bigger (I often argue that *Fringe*, Bad Robot's next work after *LOST* ended, can help one understand *LOST* better by applying it's fringe science to it).

Some viewers chose to believe that what characters experience

> was not in any way real, but my take (and the Show runners take, since they deny this view) is quite the contrary.